# random external websites redirect to localhost

Tags: redirection, xampp

I am running windows vista and recently installed xampp lite 1.7.3 to do some web development. 
I don't know if it is related to the install or something else, but now navigating to the page "www.pastebin.com" redirects me to my localhost.

The url redirects to "www.pastebin.com/xampp" on my local hosts.

I tried deleting my hosts file but that did not fix the probelm.

Any advice?
~Roy

Answer (score 1):

Well that is strange. I'm assuming you're running windows - try running

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

in a command prompt window.

Comment: "Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache." but still no pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's related to xampp, I have a working xampp install running and I can navigate to pastebin.com. Your issue seems related to DNS resolution problems.

What is the result of the command:

```
nslookup pastebin.com
```

Are you behind a proxy?

Have you tried using a public DNS like Google's 8.8.8.8?

The redirect to pastebin.com/xampp could occur if pastebin.com resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I've tried `nslookup` command and mysite.com is pointed to 127.0.0.1 and  `ipconfig -flushdns` cleared that but it takes a minutes or two.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from possible DNS issues, you can also check for a `hosts.txt` file which may be overriding DNS resolution for those domains.  I don't know the exact path where Vista would be looking for it, but previous versions of Windows kept it in the Windows system directory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try xampp/catalina_stop.bat at a CMD prompt to see if still redirects you after you stop the xampp service I believe this bat file should be available in the lite version. If the redirect goes away you at least know it is the xampp redirecting your url.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue for a random website.

- nslookup tells me that the website is indeed resolved as localhost
- checked the hosts file and disabled every custom rule, try it again, still resolved as localhost
- did ipconfig/flushdns from the windows cmd & tried again -> still resolved as localhost

**So in case you really need to access the said website**

I looked up the actual IP address, and added a rule in my host file :

> [IP]    [WEBSITE DOMAIN]

not a clean solution, but a workaround to force hostname resolution.